# Way to detect if Excel Instance is "embedded"?

Tags: excel, vba

We work with a program that embeds Excel in a larger program (SAP Xcelsius/Dashboard Designer). Is there a way, using VBA, to detect if the current instance of Excel is an `Embedded` instance or not?

The embedding occurs as a result of the command line invokation:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" -Embedding
```

Comment: Two wild guesses: `Application.Hinstance` and `Application.Parent`. Maybe you can infer from those whether Excel is embedded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... `Application.Hinstance` returns the instance number of Excel. I'm not exactly sure what that's referring to, but it looks like a memory location. In which case, that is not too useful... But the other, `Application.Parent` returns `Microsoft Excel` in the immediate window. I am inspecting the object now to see if there is something useful there.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Sergey: See my new answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in VBA:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetCommandLine Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As Long
Private Declare Function lstrlenW Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (MyDest As Any, MySource As Any, ByVal MySize As Long)

Function CmdToStr(Cmd As Long) As String
   Dim Buffer() As Byte
   Dim StrLen As Long

   If Cmd Then
      StrLen = lstrlenW(Cmd) * 2
      If StrLen Then
         ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
         CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal Cmd, StrLen
         CmdToStr = Buffer
      End If
   End If
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CmdRaw As Long
    Dim CmdLine As String
    Dim CmdArgs As Variant

    Dim ValidationType As String
    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim TargetPath As String

    CmdRaw = GetCommandLine
    CmdLine = CmdToStr(CmdRaw)

    If Strings.InStr(1, CmdLine, "-Embedding", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Call MsgBox("IsEmbedded")
    End If
End Sub
```

VBA-Base-Sourcecode taken from: https://thebestworkers.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/passing-command-line-arguments-to-a-macro-enabled-office-object/

---

Try this in C# (VSTO):

```
var isEmbedded = new List<string>(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).Contains("-Embedding");
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("IsEmbedded={0}", isEmbedded));
```